# wpf canvas and video control fullscreen

Tags: c#, wpf, video, wpf-controls

In my WPF program, I want to draw a shape. Then after I press a button, the program plays a video in fullscreen mode. I can't seem to make the video play in fullscreen on the canvas.

my XAML is like below

```
<Canvas>
    <Ellipse Name="face1" Panel.ZIndex="2" Fill="Green" Width="400" Height="400" />
    <MediaElement Panel.ZIndex="1000" Name="videoControl1" Stretch="Fill" 
                  Source="C:\Users\videos\carcrash.mp4" 
                  LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="videoControl1_MediaEnded">            
    </MediaElement>
</Canvas>
```

As you can see, I put the video in front of my shape. as sson as a button is pressed, I then start to play the video. So the video will be in front of the shape. The problem is that the video is very small. How to make it full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Dennis Cheng's comment [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b31e0b76-e57e-4ed5-b19c-69c97481f2e6/mediaelement-and-widthheight-question):

> Canvas is a "no-layout" panel so children won't size to parent. Try
>   Grid if you want children fill or manually Bind to the parent's size
>   if you must use a Canvas:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas"
    Width="300"
    Height="300">
    <Ellipse Name="face1"
            Width="400" 
            Height="400"
            Panel.ZIndex="2"
            Fill="Green" />
    <MediaElement Name="videoControl1"
                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                Path=Parent.ActualWidth}"
                Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                Path=Parent.ActualHeight}"
                Panel.ZIndex="1000"
                Source="C:\Users\videos\carcrash.mp4" />
</Canvas>
```

That scales the video's width to that of the containing Canvas, but it remains in proportion to its original dimensions.

If you use a Grid you can achieve the kind of scaling you're aiming for:

```
<Grid Width="500" Height="500">
    <Ellipse Name="face1"
            Width="400"
            Height="400"
            Panel.ZIndex="2"
            Fill="Green" />
    <MediaElement Name="videoControl1"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Panel.ZIndex="1000"
                Source="D:\Downloads\The.Strain.S01E13.HDTV.x264-LOL.mp4"
                Stretch="Fill" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you draw on 'Grid'? I need to draw Ellipse, path, etc.

Comment: How's about layering your Canvas over the MediaElement?

Comment: Great. Your method 1 already works well. thanks very very much. A small issue is that if the video has different aspect ratio from the Canvas, then the video will be distorted?

Comment: There's not much to be done about the distortion I'm afraid - you can't automagically add extra pixels to your video using MediaElement. The only things you *could* do is re-encode your video to have a different aspect ratio, or add a letterbox. There are some moderately fierce FFmpeg commands you can use to achieve that: http://superuser.com/a/547406 .